# K-Fold Cross Validation for K'-NN when K' greater than number of samples in each fold

Tags: cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to evaluate the predictive power of a K'-NN algorithm for regression. My idea is to use K-Fold Cross Validation, but the problem is: what happens if I have a K' higher than the number of samples in each fold for a given K?

An idea that i have is to use the number of neighbors in each fold as bigger as possible, as an approximation to the original model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the size of your dataset, and number of neighbors to use $K'$?

Comment: I'm using datasets with size of 25 approximately. My initial idea was to do a grid search with CV to find the best K', but what happens is that if set K folds for cross validation, there are some values of K' that wont be able to be applied in the search. The case that this situation is less problematic is using something like LOOCV (in this case the only score that I wont be allowed to have is the one corresponding to K = size of the dataset).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens until K' becomes larger than n - n/k since you always have k - 1 folds in trainng.

When all n - n/k = K' training cases are nearest neighbours, your model is not a local model any more but a global one. (At that point, the models were "almost global" for quite a while = K' already)

Comment: I agree with that, but what I want to know is what can be a good way to proceed in the case K' > n-n/k, because I cannot replicate the original model in each fold. Thanks for your answer